# Best way to share guest folder with host computer

Tags: macos, ubuntu, vmware-fusion, shared-folders

I am running a Ubuntu VM on my MacOS X (host) using VMWare Fusion. I have found a lot of information about sharing the host partition with the guest VM but not much on sharing the guest folder/partition with host. I read about using smb or nfs to do that. Isn't there an easier and faster way to do this?

Comment: What I usually do is having a specific folder on the host to use inside the guest. I use it to save documents, etc and when I turn off the guest the files are on the host. I believe it's more pratical.

Comment: If you want to do the opposite. You could use smb on Ubuntu to create a shared folder and then connect via the host using Finder (Go -> Connect to Server -> smb://the-guest-ip-address), but it needs to be connected to the network to work: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!

Comment: This is a good question, I usually use `scp/rsync` on my MacOS to get files that stored in my Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 0):

Best to map a folder of the host to be visible inside the VM (for read/write). 
The data will always be available in the host, independently of the having the VM running.
 [Check this link](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004055)